# Mixed language in admin backend

Tags: admin, language

I’m running WordPress in French and some words in admin backend are still showing in english ! Like “users” and “dashboard” and many more.

What I did :

– Switched to twenty seventeen theme
– Disabled ALL the plugins
- Deleted cache and cookies

Same problem

I tried and set WordPress in French Belgium (fr_BE) and it worked, all is in french but when I switch to French France (fr_FR), the problem returns.

I should mention that I translated the po files of the theme and some plugins to french (fr_FR) but I’ve renamed every po file I made to disable them just to see if they were the problem but nothing changed.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The problem is likely due to wordpress itself, try to ask wordpress dev to re-do the french language sites.

Comment: Actually I'm the one responsible for this Wordpress website, by re-do you mean reupload the default Wordpress installation files ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved the problem. It turns out I have mistakenly copied the .po files (fr_FR) of my theme into the /language folder and not /language/themes, so Wordpress was picking the .po of my theme and not the one from wordpress. 
I moved the po file to the themes folder and hit refresh on my website and I got a translation update. applied it and all is good now.